# How to check whether a variable passed in from flask to an html file is a certain type (e.g. string, integer)

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to web development. I'm passing in a list object ("results") from flask to my html template. I want to check if the variable I passed into the html doc is, all numericals. How would I check this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>
        Your Results
      </h1>
    </center>

    <ol>
      {% for result in results %}
        <li>
          <ul>
            {% for entry in result %}
                <li>  {{ entry }} </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          <br>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>
        Your Results
      </h1>
    </center>

    <ol>
      {% for result in results %}
        <li>
          <ul>
            {% for entry in result %}
                {% if isinstance(entry, int) or isinstance(entry, float) %}
                <li>  {{ entry }} </li>
                {% else %}
                <li>  WAS NOT AN NUMBER! </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          <br>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

If you wanted to check all results or entries, you could use list comprehension instead. Here is a simple test:

```
a = [1,2,3,4, 5.5]
b = [1,2,3, "four"]

print(len(a) == len([i for i in a if isinstance(i, (int, float))]))
print(len(b) == len([j for j in b if isinstance(j, (int,float)]))
```

**RESULTS:**

True

False

Answer (score 1):

I am kinda late to this, but if you wanted to do the check on your html, you could try creating a custom flask filter. In your app.py file type this, after you have defined your app variable

```
def check_type(stuff, types):
    if  type(stuff) == type(types):
        return True
    return False

app.jinja_env.filters['check_type'] = check_type
```

Then in your html file you could do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>
        Your Results
      </h1>
    </center>

    <ol>
      {% for result in results %}
        <li>
          <ul>
            {% for entry in result %}
                {% if entry | check_type(1) or entry | check_type(1.1) %}
                <li>  {{ entry }} </li>
                {% else %}
                <li>  WAS NOT AN NUMBER! </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          <br>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

This should work it worked for me; I am using python 3.8 by the way

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do any type checking inside your `app.py` file.

Based on your code above, it looks like you want to see the type of every `entry` in `results`, right? If that's the case, you can do this a couple ways. Since you're a beginner, you might try some simple print debugging, for example after you generate your results list you can do something like the following in your app.py:

```
for entry in results:
    print(entry, type(entry))
```

which will print each element and its type to your terminal. You could also write a function to do a boolean check for the whole `results` object:

```
def numeric_check(results):
    for entry in results:
        if isinstance(entry, int) or isinstance(entry, float):
            # note there is also a 'complex' numeric type and (in python 2.x) a 'long' type
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

You could then `print(numeric_check(results))` to see the result in your terminal.

If you want to ensure that each element is numeric without checking explicitly, you can try to coerce every element in your list to numeric with a list comprehension as follows:

```
results = [int(entry) for entry in results] 
# note you could also use 'float' as necessary
```

but you're going to run into problems, i.e. raise an exception and break your app if Python can't coerce one of the elements to numeric.

There are different ways to do this and enforce types in array-like objects using the library `numpy`, but that may be a bit advanced for you at this point.